# Entity Framework 3.5 Not adding all Properties in Model

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2008

I'm experiencing an unusual issue with Entity Framework in VS2008. The problem is when I create my Entity Model from my existing database, the designer add all the corresponding tables but it appears that it randomly omits some of my Foreign Key fields. Yet if I browse the Model in the Browser I can clearly see that the fields were included.

This became apparent when during the build I started receiving multiple errors that these fields were not mapped. This led me to manually add the fields in the designer to the corresponding tables and map them to the datasource.

After this however, I get multiple errors:
Error   102 Error 10023: Could not find the conceptual model to validate.
Error   103 Error 10024: Could not find the storage model to validate.
Error   104 Error 10025: Could not find the mapping model to validate.
Error   105 Could not find the Conceptual Schema node to embed as a resource for input file 
Error   106 Could not find the Storage Schema node to embed as a resource for input file 
Error   107 Could not find the Mapping node to embed as a resource for input file

When I open the edmx file in XML Editor, the file is riddled with squiggly lines.

I have successfully created the Entity Model in VS2010 without issue but our client isn't at 4.0 Framework.

I have identified others having the issue but I can't find any resources to assist on fixing the problem.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the `Entitiframework` reference and adding again.

Comment: This is probably because EF1 did not support foreign keys. So for foreign key columns EF will create navigation properties but will not create foreign key properties on the Entities. You can find foreign properties in model browser but this is in the model representing the database and not the conceptual models. Note that navigation properties are modeled based on foreign keys in the store and you are not losing the relationship functionality even though you don't have foreign keys.

Comment: Looks like that is exactly the issue Pawel. After reading your post and researching it, my problem is actually EF1 and being limited to the .NET 3.5 framework for this. So what options do I have for using EF1 and comprising queries that contain references to foreign keys???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably EF1 did not support foreign keys. So for foreign key columns EF will create navigation properties but will not create foreign key properties on the Entities. You can find foreign properties in model browser but this is in the model representing the database and not the conceptual model. Note that navigation properties are modeled based on foreign keys in the store and you are not losing the relationship functionality even though you don't have foreign keys exposed. In other words - if you use navigation properties in queries they will be translated correctly to use foreign key values in the SQL queries. One thing where having foreign key properties in the conceptual model is very useful is when you would like to reason or modify a relationship without having to load the related entity - if you know the key value you just set the foreign key property to this value and you are done with it. This is impossible in EF1 - whenever you need to change the relationship or query against a related entity you first need to load said entity and use navigation property.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Pawel. All things considered and with the additional information you've provided, I've decided to use the LINQTOSQL ORM instead because it doesn't have the limitations as EF1 has. If and when our client moves to the .NET 4 Framework, I will most definitely use EF4 but I'm not impressed with EF1 as it pertains to the implementation of Foreign Keys and it seems an extra step to use the navigation property when I can simply use a more direct linq query without the extra steps. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, EF1 was pretty limited in several areas. Given that you are constrained to .NET Framework 3.5 it may make sense to use Linq to SQL